# Bind jquery function to name array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i am trying to implement jQuery in my website. I have used name property of a control to bind an event like below

```
 $('[name = "OCCUPATION"]').typeahead({
             source: function (query, result) {
                var name = "test";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("lookupQuestionOption", "Home")",
                    data: { Key: query, type: name},
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {
                        result($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Now i want this single event handler for multiple controls, like it can be **OCCUPTION2 , OCCUPTION3, OCCUPTION4, OCCUPTION5...**

So the code may be like

```
$('[name = "OCCUPATION,OCCUPATION2,OCCUPATION3,OCCUPATION4"]').typeahead({
```

I have tried the above but it's not working. Please help!

Comment: You can try this `$('[name="OCCUPATION"],[name="OCCUPATION2"]')`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Alternatively, if there are a lot of inputs, each with different names, use a class instead and bind it to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector like

it will select all element whose name starts with OCCUPATION

```
$('[name ^= "OCCUPATION"]')
```

Comment: **Note**: Without the spaces.

Comment: it will work check https://jsfiddle.net/djt9k5w0/ [console] it select all elements

Comment: It will work, but it is still better practice to write it correct.